# Hibernate, getting mapping exception for uuid

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, uuid

I have a simple main class with no entity objects, plain SQL needing UUID as output. I get a mapping exception, to work around the mapping exception, I created my own custom dialect, even then the mapping exception still exists.

The hibernate version is very old, 3.2.6 and I am not able to upgrade because of few constraints. Let me know if I can still workaround.

My function looks like this:

```
SQLQuery getGidQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT gid FROM table WHERE id = " + result.getId());
UUID gid = UUID.fromString(getGidQuery.uniqueResult().toString());
```

I get the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:370)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1796)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811)
at Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

To avoid the above exception,I created my own dialect class extending the PostgresDialect, which includes the UUID dialect but the exception is still thrown.

```
public class PostgresUuidDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

public PostgresUuidDialect() {
    super();
    registerColumnType(java.sql.Types.OTHER, "pg-uuid");
}


}
```

My configuration creation

```
private static Configuration getDatabaseConfiguration(CommandLine commandLine, String database) {
    Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", commandLine.getOptionValue('u'));
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", commandLine.getOptionValue('p'));
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
            "jdbc:postgresql://" + commandLine.getOptionValue('h') + ":" + commandLine.getOptionValue("o")
                    + "/" + database + "?searchpath=" + database);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "<package>.PostgresUuidDialect");
    return configuration;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question ? From what you write, you've already dealt with this problem and everything works fine, but the question does not indicate what you would like to know more.

Comment: I'm not able to get rid of the mapping exception despite extending the PostgresSQLDialect, am I doing something wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some of the following:

```
.addScalar("ID", StringType.INSTANCE)
```

(use the proper type, not necessarily StringType)

```
RegisterHibernateType( ... )
```

in your constructor

[source](http://www.luyue.org/fix-hibernate-dialect-mapping-jdbc-type/)

Comment: That worked, since it's a really old version of hibernate, I had to go with 
    .addScalar("gid", new StringType());